# Sitemap file getting double compressed

Tags: apache, http-headers, xml-sitemap, gzip

I have a script that generates my XML sitemap and writes it to the file `sitemap.xml.gz` - i.e. an XML file, compressed with gzip. This file is definitely written correctly as when I download it via FTP it's all good.

However, when I download the file direct from the site (over HTTP), the resulting file appears to be doubly-compressed. When I unzip the file, the `sitemap.xml` file is a binary file. If I rename that to `sitemap2.xml.gz` and try unzipping again, I get the true XML file.

So I think the server (Apache2) is for some reason taking the `.gz` file and serving it with gzip compression again. The headers for the file come back as this:

```
Status: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 16 Jul 2012 00:00:47 GMT 
Server: Apache  
Last-Modified: Sun, 15 Jul 2012 23:35:26 GMT    
ETag: "89fff2-3bc46-4c4e6c48deb80"  
Accept-Ranges: bytes    
Vary: Accept-Encoding   
Content-Encoding: gzip  
Connection: close   
Transfer-Encoding: chunked  
Content-Type: application/x-gzip
```

In my httpd.conf I have this:

```
# compress all text & html:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript application/javascript
```

My VirtualHost declaration only has some mod rewrite stuff.

Anyone have any ideas why Apache might be sending the gzip header for this file?

---

**UPDATE:** I removed the `application/xml` entry from the `AddOutputFilterByType` line, and the file now downloads normally like any other binary file. However, the problem now is that regular `.xml` files are no longer sent gzipped.

So it seems like the server is deciding that `.xml.gz` files should be parsed as `application/xml`, even though it sends it with the header `application/x-gzip`.

Also, I checked the `/etc/mime-types` file, it doesn't have an entry for gzip and has this comment at the top:

> Note: Compression schemes like "gzip", "bzip", and "compress" are not
>   actually "mime-types".  They are "encodings" and hence must *not* have
>   entries in this file to map their extensions.  The "mime-type" of an
>   encoded file refers to the type of data that has been encoded, not the
>   type of encoding.

Comment: For sanity/just to see: What happens if you take a plain file and just *name* it sitemap.xml.gz?

Comment: It's very hard to be certain about the answer here.  Do you have a .htaccess file that's altering the behavior ?  Is the behavior consistent in different browsers ? (wget, ff, chrome, ie)  I would have thought that downloading the file would at the worst double compress it with the browser uncompressing and saving the sitemap.xml.gz single compressed.

Comment: @xyious no htaccess files but the rules that would normally be in htaccess are in `sites-enabled/mysite.conf` in a VirtualHost declaration. As mentioned above, they are only rewrites/redirects, nothing that would affect encoding. I tested in several browsers with the same result.

Comment: @Su' if I just rename a plain text file (3KB) to `file.txt.gz` and download it via the browser, it appears to end up as a regular gzip file (1.4KB) containing the original text file (3KB).

Comment: Based on your edit, I ran across a [ServerFault question](http://serverfault.com/questions/287821/apache-deflates-xml-gz-files) that seems to match(with solution). See if that works out for you.

Comment: @Su' yep that worked! Do you want to post that as an answer, or should I delete the question?

Comment: I'll paste it in. I hate to dupe the content, but this is one of those overlap areas, so it might be good to have the reference here also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting @cyberx86 [over at ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/287821/apache-deflates-xml-gz-files) (who you should go and vote up):

> The .xml.gz filetype may be defined as being an xml file (e.g. with forcetype in a filesmatch block) - which would cause Apache to match it to the type above.
>
> I think you can get around that by adding an exception, above it:
>
> `SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ".xml.gz$" no-gzip dont-vary`